# How can i get MAC of a device through BLE in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

How can I get MAC address of the device in objective C or swift. Is there any way to obtain MAC address from the field "Identifier".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: not possible to get mac address of peripheral in ios, so use UUID for identity of peripheral.

Comment: In iOS not possible to get peripheral mac address, ios generate UUID(identifier) for peripheral. Other way is identifier via RSSI value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No any public API for getting MAC address with BLE.

If you want to get with jailbroken device, then you can get with [this link](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=Liblockdown.dylib)

Comment: Thanks for the Info.